# which one is better? UIPanGesture? or UIDragInteraction/UIDropInteraction?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make a card game app (with swift 4) like a Solitaire Card Game.
So I have to use Drag and Drop to each Card UIView.
But I think there are two ways to use for dragging.

1. Which one is better between UIPanGesture and UIDragInteraction/UIDropInteraction?

Furthermore, I'm not sure about what panning means.
2. what is difference between dragging and panning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(From Apple site: [UIDragInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidraginteractiondelegate) & [UIPanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer)),

**UIDragInteraction**

An interaction to enable dragging of items from a view, employing a delegate to provide drag items and to respond to calls from the drag session.

**UIPanGestureRecognizer**

A concrete subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that looks for panning (dragging) gestures.

Here, Pan & Drag gesture is almost same.
Some of differences which I got from searching are as follow..

- UIDragInteraction works from iOS 11.0+ & UIPanGestureRecognizer works from iOS 3.2+, so if you want to run your application in older version devices then you should use UIPanGestureRecognizer
- UIPanGestureRecognizer works on the whole screen & gives you the CGPoints as response of touch where UIDragInteraction works on the particular object you want to drag & drop & gives you direct the view object.
- UIPanGestureRecognizer can work with multiple touches & handle those where UIDragInteraction doesn't allow you to handle multiple touch.

Hope this helps.

Thanks